# eventstore socket receive error

Tags: eventstoredb

I am using the .Net EventStore and to append a basic event to a stream as follows:

```
IEventStoreConnection conn = EventStoreConnection.Create(
new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1113));

conn.ConnectAsync().Wait();

int i = 100;
EventData e = new EventData(
    Guid.NewGuid(),
    "eventType",
    true,
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"somedata\" : " + i + "}"),
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("{\"metadata\" : " + i + "}")
);

conn.AppendToStreamAsync("test", ExpectedVersion.Any, e);
```

I am getting the following "socket receive error":

```
[16244,37,12:46:52.925] External TCP connection accepted: [Normal, 127.0.0.1:56476, L127.0.0.1:1113, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}].
[16244,37,12:46:52.957] ES TcpConnection closed [12:46:52.957: N127.0.0.1:56476, L127.0.0.1:1113, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}]:Received bytes: 0, Sent bytes: 0
[16244,37,12:46:52.957] ES TcpConnection closed [12:46:52.957: N127.0.0.1:56476, L127.0.0.1:1113, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}]:Send calls: 0, callbacks: 0
[16244,37,12:46:52.957] ES TcpConnection closed [12:46:52.957: N127.0.0.1:56476, L127.0.0.1:1113, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}]:Receive calls: 1, callbacks: 1
[16244,37,12:46:52.957] ES TcpConnection closed [12:46:52.957: N127.0.0.1:56476, L127.0.0.1:1113, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}]:Close reason: [ConnectionReset] Socket receive error
[16244,37,12:46:52.957] Connection 'external-normal' [127.0.0.1:56476, {54565547-1dea-4ff5-acce-f2ebc0ff5d15}] closed: ConnectionReset.
```

Any idea why? THANKS :-)

What this means is the event written to the stream is not pushed to subscribing clients...

Comment: Normally security error ..